# Adding Facebook Insights on domain = No admin data found

Tags: facebook, analytics, facebook-insights

It should be so easy but for some reason I just cant succeed adding Facebook Insights to my domain. I have added the fb:admins metatags with my profile ID and the Facebook Debugger can find the tag - but still I get this error when trying to add the domain

> No admin data found at root webpage 'http://www.alkoholprocent.dk/'.
>   Insights requires admin data at the root webpage for the domain
>   'www.alkoholprocent.dk'....

It is probably some stupid small thing I have missed but please enlighten me!

Comment: I don’t see those tags in the source code of the page either.

Comment: "Those tags" - guess it is only one tag? And what does line 12 show then? The meta is only added to the default-page.

Comment: Looks like you just added `fb:admins`, and now the debug tool picks it up too.

Comment: What the h*** - I have done nothing for the past 3-4 hours and now suddently it also works in Facebook! Must be some cache or something. Weird - but thnx :)